# Get selected item using JQuery AutoComplete

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the code below working.  How do I read and set the item selected to a control on the page (i.e. hidden field).  NomineeUserName is a property on the object being returned.  Thanks for any help provided.

```
$(function () {
$(".tb").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Service/NomineeWebService.asmx/GetMatchingActiveDirectoryUsers",
            data: "{ 'SearchCharacters': '" + request.term + "' }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        id: item.NomineeUserName,
                        value: item.NomineeLastNameFirstName,
                        data: item
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        selectedItemData = ui.item.data;
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `select` handler, it should be pretty simple:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    $("hidden-input-selector").val(ui.item.id);
}
```